# Getting OAuth Refresh Token Error UNAUTHORISED ERROR when hitting Bigtable

Tags: exception, oauth-2.0, hbase, google-cloud-bigtable

I have an app that uses Bigtable-hbase api for creating an Bigtable Connection using Service Account File.
This works fine in the local and sometimes on weblogic server also.
But after some request through the api , I am getting the following error -

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Unexpected failure get auth token at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:365)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.refreshCredentials(RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.java:379)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.access$100(RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.java:60)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor$2.call(RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.java:328)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.io.RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor$2.call(RefreshingOAuth2CredentialsInterceptor.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)>
```

I am using following configuration to create the connection  -

```
Configuration config = BigtableConfiguration.configure(projectId,instanceId);
    config.set(BigtableOptionsFactory.BIGTABLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_KEYFILE_LOCATION_KEY, new File(filePath).toString());       
    
Connection btConnection=ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
    
//then the code to read and write into the table`...
```

These code works fine sometimes and after some request it is throwing the above error.
I need to reason why it is happening and how can I resolve it so that application works fine when we sent the bulk request.
I think issue might be access refresh token , but how can I solve it?

Comment: go to your service account details page and from there check the "**Key expiration date**" then set it to what suits you.

Comment: "Key expiration date" is set to **Jan 1, 10000**. Do I need to change it?

Comment: from what I see your key hasn't expire and it shouldn't give such an error. can you tell me what version of bigtable-hbase are you using? where is your application is deployed? approximatly, after how much time does the errors start to show up? locally, does it work always or you see the errors also after sometime? are you using a default service account or custom service account?

Comment: Dependency bigtable-hbase-1.x  version  - 1.0.0

Comment: Application is depolyed on apache weblogic server and the error is coming nearly after 1 hr on the server. In the local I tried my best to replicate but it is not coming.

Comment: I am using custom service account.

Comment: Hi @Manoj , can you upgrade your dependency to the latest version? I see there is a new version 1.15.0. check full list here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.bigtable/bigtable-hbase

Comment: Updated and also can you please tell to is the correct way to refresh credential.   `BigtableOptions options = BigtableOptionsFactory.fromConfiguration(btConfigs);
   Credentials credentials = CredentialFactory.getCredentials(options.getCredentialOptions());
   log.info("Attempting credential refresh...");
   credentials.refresh();
   log.info("Credential refreshed successfully!!!");`

Comment: you don't need to refresh the token yourself. the client library should do this on your behalf if everything works fine

Comment: Thanks @MethkalKhalawi it works fine now in weblogic server.